# comparing fact tables of different granularity

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have fact tables describing [events] and [event_segment] and [event_staff].

[events] are composed of many [event_segment] - e.g. 'introduction', 'pre-check', '1st stage', '2nd stage' etc. The key (i.e. granular unique id) for [events] is [event_ref], however the key (i.e. unique identifier) for [event_segment] is composite - [event_ref] and [segment_order]

[event_staff] has many staff to 1 event, so the unique id is composite of [event_ref] and [staff_id]

There are several conformed dimensions - e.g. day, location etc.

I am struggling to decide on a model for this data, as I want to allow easy comparison of aggregated facts across the 3 tables, particularly in reporting. i.e. count([staff]) vs sum([event_segment_duration]) where [staff_type] = 'basic' and [event_segment_type] != 'clean up'

Because there are many staff attending an event, many segments to an event, but I cannot tie staff to a segment I have to group on [event_ref].

This 'works', but does it count as breaking Kimball/Data warehouse standards as it is joining (well grouping on) events?

Also, should [event_ref] exist in [event_segment] table, as it should be surrogate key, and therefore not available to group on?

Comment: You might get more/better answers at the [Database Administrators site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: this is not about Database Administration, this is about data modeling/database design

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are breaking any standard.

It just happened to you that you have two additional fact tables with a different level of granularity.

In my opinion you can consider the segment like a child of the event, so you can consider segment part of the event dimension.

The staff is just a different dimension (never a good idea to split a dimension to multiple children) and it happens that the lowest level of the staff dimension doesn't meet the lowest level of the event one.

This is a normal real word scenario and it's quite frequent, you can imagine a football team, you can have some game stats associated to `Player`s (children), some associated to the `Team` (parent), but also some other information like tickets sold for each `Game` (different dimension) that cannot be associated to a specific player, but the for sure have more detail than just at `Team` level.